# Maybe we should have 2-3 featured questions daily

Tags: discussion

Sometimes you ask a question and then you find out it is a duplicate. Often times you missed it and did not notice it. Maybe we should take old questions that are appropiate to the time of year and have them featured daily at the top of the questions or under a featured question tab?

Comment: Speaking of duplicates, check out [this question](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/288/a-way-to-bring-attention-to-timely-questions) 8^D. I think daily might be a bit much to maintain, but a weekly feature like I outlined there could work. If you're interested in trying to implement it, give it a shot! If you want to try bountying timely questions so they come up as featured, go for it.

Comment: Often, the suggested related questions that come up after you type in your title show possible duplicates.