# What happened to Lo.yodeya.com?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Based on http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=1934355#1934355

Is http://lo.yodeya.com/ still connected to judaism.se? If yes, why is it not used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "yodeya" brand is [currently](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/proposed-faq-language-explaining-mi-yodeya-references) an unofficial alternative name/URL for Judaism.SE. I own the yodeya.com and miyodeya.com domains and point mi.yodeya.com, yodeya.com, and miyodeya.com to Judaism.SE. I also control the blog that lo.yodeya.com points to. So, technically speaking, there's no reason we couldn't use it.

On the other hand, if we had something to blog about, it would probably make more sense to get an official [blogoverflow.com](http://blogoverflow.com/) blog and take advantage of the built-in tie-ins with our site and the rest of the SE network. So far, though, no one has volunteered to do any sort of regular blogging, which is what would be necessary to make it worth setting up a blog. We've [had](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/282/idea-weekly-podcast) [some](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281/idea-weekly-topic-challenges) [ideas](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342/maybe-we-should-have-2-3-featured-questions-daily) for regular content that could go in a blog, but like I said, no volunteers.

If someone wants to take up one of these ideas (or something else) and start writing weekly, we could request to have a blog set up. The best way to demonstrate that you're willing and able to do this is to just start doing it on meta.

Back to your quotation from chat, unless we have a blog that's fully integrated into the site, meta remains the best place to put site announcements. If we did site announcements on lo.yodeya, almost no one would know about them. In addition, the access controls and user identities for posting, responding, and editing here (or in an integrated blog) are all set, unlike with lo.yodeya, which exists on an unrelated platform (Blogger).

Comment: Would anybody be interested in seeding a blog with stuff that J.SE users are already posting to their own blogs?  With cross-links in both directions it seems like everybody could benefit -- and it might encourage new content.  I don't know how SE blogs work; is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: @Monica interesting idea. Could you please post it as a meta question? Then it will get more attention from other users as well as hopefully from SE staff.

Comment: done: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/382/use-our-blog-to-share-content-from-our-users-own-blogs