# Use our blog to share content from our users' own blogs?

Tags: discussion, blog

(This started in comments [on this question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-happened-to-lo-yodeya-com).)

We have the ability [to associate a blog with our site](http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/), but the big question with blogs is always content.  Would it be worth seeding a blog with stuff that J.SE users are already posting to their own blogs? With cross-links in both directions it seems like everybody could benefit -- and it might encourage new blog content and new questions.

As a tiny example, I have a general-purpose blog (not limited to Jewish topics) on which I post a little teaching from the daf yomi once a week.  It's just a trifle, for beginners mainly, but I would be happy to share those posts here if people wanted.  And I suspect that most of us who have blogs have posted the occasional d'var torah; why not collect them here?  Any repost here would link to the original post and we would ask people to link from the original post to the J.SE blog, perhaps drawing their readers here.

It seems like this would be valuable in a few ways:

- Publicizing Judaism.SE via the links from those other blogs.
- Providing a way to get to know some of our contributors through more general writings and not just their answers and questions.  In other words, it helps with community-building.
- It gives us a place to post material of interest to our community that doesn't fit the Q&A format, such as divrei torah.  (Blog posts should feel free to link to individual questions, of course.)
- By being part of the SE blog aggregate (once we graduate), it provides another entry point into our site from the greater SE community.

I'd like to use this (edited) post to see what regular content could be available.  If you, personally, already post Jewish content elsewhere that you think would fit our blog, and you would be willing to contribute it here as described above, please answer with the following:

- Type of content (topic, level, etc)
- How frequently you can provide new posts
- If possible, links to sample posts

One topic per answer, please.

Comment: I love this idea! Hopefully it will come into fruition.

Comment: There may be a need to be selective about which blogs to republish, if we want our blog to have an independent reputation for quality.

Comment: @IsaacMoses agreed, we'll need to have some sort of review process for content we publish under our banner.  And I'm not assuming that everything from any given blog (or blog + tags) would automatically be in the pipeline; blog authors and the community may need to be more selective.

Answer (score 4):

I think there would be a purpose served by gathering Torah posts people have (that don't fit into the Q&A format) together in one place. There are many small blogs that don't get much readership, but if their top posts could be gathered in one place, it might make for a high-quality blog. I don't know how it would fit into the StackExchange system though. If anyone's interested I can probably contribute http://TorahJournal.com to such a purpose (it's currently down while I transfer my web host).

Comment: I think the idea would be to use this sort of content as the bedrock for a blog on [BlogOverflow](http://blogoverflow.com/), officially associated with J.SE. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-happened-to-lo-yodeya-com/381#381

Comment: If they're meant for that kind of blog roundup, then I think its worth a try.

Comment: I don't think any of them are currently used for that, but that wouldn't necessarily prevent us from doing so.

Comment: It seems there's a CS theory blog affiliated with the CS theory stack exchange site: http://feedworld.net/toc/ (at least there were ads for it on the site).

Answer (score 2):

Topic: short, beginner-level teachings from the daf yomi (very occasionally a non-daf talmud teaching if it's seasonal).

Frequency: weekly (Thursdays), unless bumped by a holiday or vacation

[Samples](http://cellio.livejournal.com/tag/daf%20bits) (this link is to the "daf bits" tag on my blog).

Comment: And if this is too basic for this site that's cool; it's what I can offer that would be regular.  (If a blog already exists I'd share the irregular divrei torah and the like, but to get a blog going we need regular updates.)

Answer (score 0):

http://lessonsintorah.blogspot.com/ I opened a blog for everyone to share any insights in the Torah. The password will be available to whoever wants it.

Comment: But see http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/: we can do a blog that is strongly linked to and from this site, and IMO that'd be best if we're starting a site blog.

Comment: @msh210 why not? Just wanted to put some ideas into action.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  If we're going to set up a blog I'd rather take advantage of SE's infrastructure to run it instead of setting out on our own; we get better integration that way, e.g. their blog aggregator.  Also, I don't know how big a deal this is, but more employers and schools block Blogspot than block SE.