# What would be the best format for the Torah Blog Roundup?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, blog

(This is a continuation from [this question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/use-our-blog-to-share-content-from-our-users-own-blogs))
Since it seems there's enough interest in creating a blog roundup from different users with Torah Blogs, it seems worth figuring out what format it should have. These are some different possibilities, though it can also be a combination of them:

- Editors approve what articles get displayed on website. So if there are many submissions, only the best ones (according to the editors) will be displayed on the site.
- RSS feeds automatically collect all posts from approved blogs and display them on site chronologically, regardless of the quality of specific post. The important part is then just approving the high-quality blogs.
- Anyone can submit their posts and users can then vote up the best articles. The voting will be like SE, but the site itself will be more like Digg or Reddit. Could use either [Pligg](http://pligg.com/) or [Reddit](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki) software. The issue would be getting enough users to actually vote up best articles.

Perhaps the site can start with editor-approved feeds, but then transition to user-voted or editor-approved articles. RSS feeds can also remain a side-feature of the site.

Comment: My initial thought was that a few known user/bloggers would be given posting privileges, and they would each manually cross-post material from their blogs at their own discretion, possibly governed by an agreement to each post once per week, maybe even on a certain day each, or something like that.

Comment: @tomsmith, see [BlogOverflow](http://blogoverflow.com/). I don't think any of them are currently doing this sort of round-up concept.

Comment: I'd like to not *only* do the RSS approach, because it cuts out people who post on a variety of topics.

Comment: I added one answer version, people can add others if they want.

Answer (score 2):

Allow certain people to submit their blog posts directly to the main page (perhaps based on a certain score on the blog site or Judaism.SE). Other people can submit to a secondary page, where it can either be voted up or approved by an editor to display on the main page.

Comment: I don't know. That's why in the question I suggested Reddit or Pligg as software.