# Now that we graduated, should we do a blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

We discussed making a [blog](http://lo.yodeya.com) in a [previous](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/use-our-blog-to-share-content-from-our-users-own-blogs) [post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/380/732).

Now that we graduated, what do people think about starting an official Mi Yodeya blog?

Comment: What would we blog about?

Comment: Parsha, Torah, Halacha on the Week,

Comment: @DoubleAA, About Jewish Life and Learning, of course.

Comment: I suggested that the Christianity blog do a collaboration with your blog on [different approaches to the same text](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/978/214), but I suspect the result might be more interesting to Christians than to you. But a series of essays on how you look at the same text and see things differently could be worthwhile. Ideally, it would be a tie-in between the two blogs, but I suppose as you don't have one yet it could all go on the Christianity blog.

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely! But this comes with several caveats.

- We need *several* people to agree *beforehand* to write up posts/updates/divrei Torah on a regular basis. Ideally, these should be community members, but if we got guest posts once in a while from outside bloggers, that would be fantastic!
- Authors must be aware that they're writing for not only our community (which is made up mostly of people who are very fluent in Jewish concepts). This blog *must* (IMO) cater to "those who are interested in knowing more". That means dejargonifying, etc. and making the blog more welcoming to those outside our community.

---

Here are some ideas on what we could blog about:

- Weekly Parsha
- Upcoming Holidays
- Halacha of the Week (Like Shmuel said)
- Jewish life

That's mostly your standard Jewish blog fare, but we could also do more site specific stuff:

- Highlight interesting Q&A (individual questions or groups on common themes/tags or weekly/monthly round-up)
- A summary of the week's Parsha Chat
- Perhaps welcomes to new value-contributing users? (Criteria being upvotes posts, rep, whatever.)
- General community news (welcome back Yahu, no Parsha Chat this week, mod x will be off site for a while, whatever.)
- Interviews with community members.

The above community items don't have to be solo posts, they could be combined in a weekly roundup, or whatever.

(Feel free to answer with your own ideas for blog content)

Comment: +1 for great question/answer round-up and summary of the weekly parsha chat.

Comment: For divrei torah, maybe set up some sort of rotation so people could sign up for particular parshiyot in advance?

Comment: @MonicaCellio That's an excellent idea!

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Wasn't it you who said http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=4278398#4278398 ? Ok, he's not active much, but if he ever was, that could be blog-worthy news! :D

Comment: +1, but I don't think that the original content has to be limited to Torah topics. Other site-topical topics would be good, too, such as stuff a blogger dug up during an attempt to answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15079, or even, say, household tips directly related to Jewish life.

Comment: @msh210 Write up an answer, or add it to this one!

Comment: @HodofHod, all right: I've edited this one. Thanks.

Comment: Did this end up happening in the end?

Answer (score 1):

We can also use our blog to reshare relevant posts from our users' blogs, [as described here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/382/472).  Answers there contain a few volunteers (we should check for continued applicability since the post is old), and see also [this new offer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1866/472).

Between the ideas here and those on the linked posts, I think we have enough interest to pursue a blog.  We should aim for a mix of "reshares" and original content, and the original content should cover both original articles (like those in HodofHod's answer) and ones that interact with the Q&A on our site.