# articles based on the weekly daf yomi

Tags: discussion, scope, daf-yomi

I write a weekly article on one of the hot topics learnt in Daf Yomi. 
I'd be happy to post it here to hear what you have to say, is that within the boundaries of this website?

Comment: Related (on the subject of a blog linked to the site): http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1094/472, http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/382/472.

Answer (score 1):

[As described in "About Mi Yodeya"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/about), this is a question-and-answer site. All question posts are questions that might arise in real life (e.g. when learning *daf yomi*). So posting a *chidush* on the *daf*, or a summary of commentarie, or the like, is out; asking for an interpretation and posting one as an answer is all right, however: but [make sure the question is written well](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/307).

Comment: But maybe it's time to revive discussions of our blog?  If we have enough people who'll contribute regularly, I'd love to have this content as part of it.  (I've linked a couple relevant posts in a comment on the question.)

Comment: whats the conclusion, it seems that we all think it should happen, but is it actually going to kick off!

Comment: I just added [this](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1869/472) to the "should we do a blog?" question.  Let's use that question to discuss a blog, and then if we do a blog I'd love to have your articles @rabbi.  Meanwhile, any that you can cast as Q&A that fits our site would be welcome there; we've had other "what does this daf mean?" questions so that would be right at home.